# How to detect is TCPConn alive

Tags: go

I have several TCPConn objects. I want to run goroutine that will periodically check are my TCPConns alive, and if someone is dead  I wanna close these TCPConn and delete from memory.

How can I check is TCPConn object alive? I did not found similar method in net lib docs.

Comment: I know I can try to read from TCPConn but if there was important message to me It will be lost because i spend this read just for checking.
My logic is located in one place, goroutine-checker - in another.

Comment: You have to execute a read or write op to determine if the connection is active. You'll need to refactor your code. Most TCP applications that use keepalive connections use some sort of heartbeat signal for verifying that the client is alive and well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sensibly cannot.

But this is not about Go but rather TCP/IP in principle.

There are multiple aspects of why you can't:

- Such a check — if existed — would be inherently racy: for instance, as soon as the check returned "all OK", the remote end could send you a packet with `RST`.

  It's much like checking a file on a filesystem exists before attempting to read from it: as soon as the check asked the filesystem whether the file exists, and it answered "yes", any other process could delete the file, so the attempt at opening the beleived-to-be-existing file would fail.

  Also think of a perfectly viable possibility of your process contending for CPU time with other processes running in the system: what in your program's code looks like two adjacent operations might be separated by lots of wall-clock time when the kernel deprives your process of CPU time for whatever reason.
- There is no concept of "TCP connection health" which TCP/IP stacks of popular kernels would expose.

  For instance, suppose you have sent a couple of bytes to the remote end and the TCP stack on your local system waits to hear their reception acknowledged by the remote TCP stack.
  There's no way you could make TCP stack tell that something appears to "stall" to your userspace code.

  The situation with remote side is worse: if the remote party attempts to send you something and that stalls for whatever reason, there is simply no way for it to communicate that fact to you: because the communication link is stalling after all, so no communication is possible.

---

There still exist a couple of approaches to tackle this problem.

- Implement "pings" in your application-level protocol ("heartbeats" — as @Adrian suggested in their comment — is another popular moniker for such functionality).

  Say, if a party participating in the communication did not send anyting during the specified time period, it had to send some "ping" message and then expect the remote end to respond to it with a "pong" message back, and that should happen in a configured time frame; if the pong does not arrive in that time frame, you deem the communication link as broken.
- Enable TCP keepalives on your connection — through using its [`net.TCPConn.SetKeepalive*` methods](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetKeepAlive) — and rely on them to proactively detect communication outages.

  This mechanism makes the TCP stack send special probe frames to the remote end if the connection is otherwise idle.
  If such probing fails, the socket will be closed by the kernel, and this will appear to your code as a "socket is ready" event with the nearst attempt to read and/or write to it failing with an error.

Note that TCP keepalives are a complicated beast and you might need to study how they work, whether the kernels at both sides of the link require tweaking and test your solution in the presense of artifical link failures.
You might start your journey [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/when-tcp-sockets-refuse-to-die/).